# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < for GET requests in production mode

Tags: node.js, heroku, routes, create-react-app, production

I have deployed my program in Heroku(Node backend and React for frontend by create-react-app). It's working well for POST requests but for GET requests I'm receiving

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I have this code in app.js for the absolute path for build folder in front-end folder:

```
let root = path.join(__dirname, 'front-end', 'build'); // (on Heroku ==>  
path.join(__dirname, 'front-end', 'build'); )
app.use(express.static(root));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.method === 'GET' && req.accepts('html') && !req.is('json') &&!req.path.includes('.')) {
      res.sendFile('index.html', { root });
   } else next();
 });
```

[image: project folder]

How can I fix this part to work for GET request as well?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: This is probably happening because you're getting an HTML response for one of your requests. Check in the network tab in your developer tools. You might be getting an HTML response for your GET requests.

Comment: @sudobangbang Yes, exactly and I'm receiving the HTML file in build folder because I'm already pointing to that as it is single page application(As for single page app structure, when the URL is called for the first time, the whole page layout has to be loaded first.) I just wonder how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my answer to change add the header to my fetch request in front-end as well Because here I'm checking the

> req.method === 'GET'

So I have added the header to the request:

```
fetch('/alladmins', { 
     headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept" : "application/json"}
      })
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then((data) => { this.setState({ arrayOfAdmins: data });
  }
  , 
  function (error) {
    console.error("Error with fetching /alladmins url:", error);
  });
```

And it's working now, kinda weird because **GET** should not need this header but it's working.